# Twilio Websocket Get Incoming URL or Variable

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am using Twilio websocket to connect to my nodejs server and all is working fine.

I want to get the incoming host/url on my nodejs server e.g wss://DDDDDDDDD.com:8080/?USERID=22222222 is the incoming url that will connect to my nodejs websocket server.

I want to be able to get the $get[USERID] from the url and use it on the nodejs server.

Below is some of the nodejs server code.

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
console.log("New Connection Initiated");

 /// Here I want to get the URL of the incoming connection so that I can take the $get[USERID] out of it.

});
```